# Bundle install throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using ubuntu 12.04. My Rails project throws some error while executing the command `bundle install`. The errors are:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /var/lib/gems (Errno::EACCES)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:217:in `mkpath'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:215:in `reverse_each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:215:in `mkpath'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:201:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:201:in `mkpath'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:1035:in `mkpath'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/installer.rb:15:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:13
```

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this instead:

```
$ sudo bundle install
```

If you don't like this and really care, [chown](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) [gem folders](http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.com/2009/06/find-your-ruby-gems-path.html) as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that it needs file access permissions (`Permission denied - /var/lib/gems`). It is trying to create a directory with `mkdir`, but failing

Comment: chown $USER -R ~/.blabla,   command not working for changing the permissions. what can i do? @Hitham

Comment: Contact the system admin

Answer (score 0):

`$ bundle install --path=/path/you/can/write/to`